# How to improve Ignite performance?

Tags: benchmarking, ignite

I'm benchmarking Ignite and running the following tests:

1. Get 5K keys out of 100K/1M (3K are matched) using 
   cache.getAll(keys)
2. Query out of 100K/1M using:

   List keys = cache.query(new ScanQuery(
   (k, p) -> p.getSalary() > 900000)
   Cache.Entry::getKey).getAll();

I have tuned Durable Memory as suggested [here](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/durable-memory-tuning) and I'm using separate ssd for storagePath and walPath but the results are not so good:

```
case 1 using 100K - 4,761ms
case 1 using 1M - 4,979
case 2 using 100K - 250ms
case 2 using 1M - 2,207ms
```

my object size is 1k. This is it:

```
public class MyPerson implements Serializable 
{
   /** Resume text (create LUCENE-based TEXT index for this field). */
   @QueryTextField
   private String resume;

   /** MyPerson ID (indexed). */
   @QuerySqlField(index = true)
   private Long id;

   /** Organization ID (indexed). */
   @QuerySqlField(index = true)
   private Long orgId;

   /** First name (not-indexed). */
   @QuerySqlField
   private String firstName;

   /** Last name (not indexed). */
   @QuerySqlField
   private String lastName;

   /** Salary (indexed). */
   @QuerySqlField(index = true)
   private double salary;

   public void setResume(String resume) {
      this.resume = resume;
   }

   public Long getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public MyPerson(Long id){
      this.id = id;
   }

   public double getSalary() {
      return salary;
   }

   public void setSalary(double salary) {
      this.salary = salary;
   }
}
```

How can I improve my results?

Thanks,

Alon

Comment: 1. How are you run benchmarks? Is it possible 1 case force load data from store and 2-nd one was run over in-memory data?  
2. What is cache configuration? it is transactional?  
3. You've configured SQL indices. ScanQuery can't use them. Have you tried to test SqlQuery?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducer? This way others would be able to reproduce your results and provide suggestions.